# pyspark filtering rows by corresponding condition

Tags: pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have two tables:

```
df_1:
| condition | date           |
| --------  | -------------- |
| A         | 2018-01-01     |
| A         | 2018-01-02     |
| A         | 2018-01-03     |
| B         | 2018-04-04     |
| B         | 2018-04-05     |
| B         | 2018-04-06     |

df_2: 
| condition | date           |
| --------  | -------------- |
| A         | 2018-01-01     |
| B         | 2018-04-05     |
```

I want to filter Table 1 by the dates in Table 2 such that I only keep the entries of df_1 that the date is greater that its corresponding date in df_2, this is the expected output:

```
| condition | date           |
| --------  | -------------- |
| A         | 2018-01-02     |
| A         | 2018-01-03     |
| B         | 2018-04-06     |
```

One way of doing this in pandas is to loop through the rows in df_2

```py
all_dfs=[]
for idx,row in df_2.iterrows():
    filtered_df = df_1[(df_1['condition']==row['condition'])&(df_1['date']>row['date'])]
    all_dfs.append(filtered_df)
final_df = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=0)
```

How do I do this in pyspark that does not involve a for loop?

Comment: Use left anti join: `df_1.join(df_2, (df_1['condition'] == df_2['condition']) & (df_1['date'] <= df_2['date']), "left_anti")`

Comment: The `anti join` will fail is the `df_1` has row ` C | 2018-01-01`. Basically when the condition is not present in `df_2` will be included in the result. `left_semi` has the same behaviour as OP's pandas code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark has the [`left_semi`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#semi-join) join exactly for this usecase.

## Example

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from datetime import datetime


schema = StructType([StructField('condition', StringType()), StructField('date',DateType())])
df_1_rows = [Row("A", datetime.strptime("2018-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("A", datetime.strptime("2018-01-02", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("A", datetime.strptime("2018-01-03", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("B", datetime.strptime("2018-04-04", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("B", datetime.strptime("2018-04-05", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("B", datetime.strptime("2018-04-06", "%Y-%m-%d")),]
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(df_1_rows, schema)

df_2_rows = [Row("A", datetime.strptime("2018-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")),Row("B", datetime.strptime("2018-04-05", "%Y-%m-%d"))]
df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(df_2_rows, schema)

df_1.join(df_2, (df_1['condition'] == df_2['condition']) & (df_1['date'] > df_2['date']), "left_semi").show()
```

### Output

```
+---------+----------+
|condition|      date|
+---------+----------+
|        A|2018-01-02|
|        A|2018-01-03|
|        B|2018-04-06|
+---------+----------+
```